# Modificar un int a formato DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: javascript

Debo modificar desde JavaScript un int que viene asi: 20200206 es decir tengo 2020 como año 02 como mes y 06 como día y tengo que pasarlo como string así "06-02-2020". Pensé que esta función me ayudaba pero veo que no hace lo que yo quiero.

```
var datepay = new Date();
datepay.setTime(20200206);
console.log(`setTime(): ${datepay}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Un modo sencillo es convertir int a string y colocar en el orden que necesites los elementos con substring, ya que no es un formato estándar de [fecha](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp).

```js
var fecha = 20200206;
var sfecha = fecha.toString();
fechaformat = sfecha.substring(6, 8) + "-" + sfecha.substring(4, 6) + "-" + sfecha.substring(0, 4) ;
console.log(fechaformat);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getFormattedDate(dateNum) {

  function pad(val) {
    return val < 10 ? `0${val}` : val;
  }
  
  const dateStr = (dateNum).toString();
  const match = dateStr.match(/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/);
  
  if (!match) return null;
  const [, year, month, d] = match;
  const date = new Date(year, month - 1, d);
  console.log(date);
  return `${pad(date.getDate())}-${pad(date.getMonth()+1)}-${date.getFullYear()}`;
}

console.log(getFormattedDate(20200206))
```

Comment: Me gusta que esta solución valida que el formato corresponda al esperado para construir la fecha y usa un tipo de dato adecuado para alojar el valor y de ahí obtener sus componentes. Además, la entrega como un método que se puede reusar fácilmente.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes primero pasarla a cadena y luego crear sub cadenas de la misma para finalmente formar un objeto de tipo date y una vez con la fecha convertida puedes jugar con los metodos `getDay()`, `getMonth()` y `getFullYear()` para obtener el formato deseado.

```
var fecha = String(20200206);
var ano = fecha.substring(0,4);
var mes = fecha.substring(4,6);
var dia = fecha.substring(6,8);

var fechaConvertida  = new Date(ano, mes-1, dia);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const fulldate = 20200206;
const year = (fulldate / 10000) | 0;
const mesYDia = (fulldate / 10000).toString().split('.')[1];
const mes = parseInt(mesYDia[0] + mesYDia[1]) - 1;
const dia = parseInt(mesYDia[2] + mesYDia[3]);
  
const datepay = new Date(year,  mes,  dia).toLocaleDateString("en-GB").replace(/\//g, "-");
console.log(datepay);
```

La forma en que funciona este algoritmo es muy sencilla, para obtener el año dividimos tu numero entero entre 10000 y lo casteamos a un int:

```
const year = (fulldate / 10000) | 0;
```

Para obtener el mes y el día por separados, debemos primero obtenerlos en conjunto, para ello, hacemos lo mismo que lo anterior pero sin castear a int, luego lo que hacemos es convertir todo eso a una cadena de texto, dividirlo atravez del punto y obtener solo la parte de la derecha, es decir, obtenemos el mes y el dia juntos en ese orden:

```
const mesYDia = (fulldate / 10000).toString().split('.')[1];
```

para obtener solo el **mes** podemos juntar los primeros dos caracteres de la cadena de texto obtenida anteriormente y luego esto pasarlo a un entero, tener en cuenta que el objeto `Date`, recibe el mes como un numero comprendido entre e incluyendo el 0, hasta e incluyendo el 11, por lo tanto como el mes seguramente venga en formato de 1 a 12, debemos restarle uno, para obtener correctamente el mes:

```
const mes = parseInt(mesYDia[0] + mesYDia[1]) - 1;
```

Para obtener el día, hacemos lo mismo que lo anterior, lo único es que en vez de juntar el primer y segundo carácter de nuestra cadena obtenida en la constante `mesYDia` lo que hacemos es juntar el 3er y cuarto carácter de nuestra cadena y luego pasarlos a un numero entero.

Por ultimo tenemos lo siguiente:

```
const datepay = new Date(year,  mes,  dia);
```

Lo que hacemos ahí es primero crear un nuevo objeto `Date`, notese que este objeto puede recibir ciertos parametros, en este caso en ese orden recibe el año, mes y el día.

Esto nos devolvera un formato de fecha no deseado realmente teniendo en cuenta el formato que deseas, por lo que usamos la función:

```
toLocaleDateString()
```

La cual hace parte de la clase `Date` y nos permite obtener una fecha como cadena de texto dependiente del formato regional especificado, si no se le especifica un formato entonces se usara el formato de fecha configurado actualmente en tu pc, `linux, mac, windows` etc.

Precisamente cuando ponemos:

```
const datepay = new Date(year,  mes,  dia).toLocaleDateString("en-GB")
```

Lo que nos devuelve esto es una cadena de texto con el siguiente formato:

```
DD/MM/YYYY
```

Esto debido a que el ingles britanico usa este formato de fecha, pero claro, tu no deseas que el formato este con barras, lo deseas es con estas otras barras (-), por este motivo al final de todo esto ponemos:

```
replace(/\//g, "-");
```

Que lo que hace es exactamente eso, reemplazar todas las barras (/) por este caracter (-), que hayan en el string.

Comment: Mas tarde quiza edite la respuesta y ponga un poco de explicacion,  sin embargo aqui esta tarde y estoy en el movil,  no quice ponerme a hacer comentarios en el movil acerca del codigo,  mañana edito la respuesta y pongo un poco mas de informacion al respecto.